# Confused about overriding CSS styles

Tags: css

I understand CSS basics, but I keep running into trouble with conflicting styles. Consider the following styles.

First, the default font color in my style sheets is black. I want that color applied to all picture captions - unless they're contained in divs with a class CoolL or CoolR...

```
.CoolL .Caption, .CoolR .Caption { color: #900; }
```

Now all the captions in the Cool series have brown text. But there are situations where I want the captions to have a black background with white text, so I created this rule:

```
.Black { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

Now consider the following HTML. Class Caption by itself should have black text. However, this is inside a div with a class CoolR, so it displays brown text instead. But I added the class Black to the last div, which should change the background to black and the text color to white...

```
<div class="CoolR Plus Max300">
  <div class="Shadow2">
    <img src="">
    <div class="Caption Black">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In fact, the background is displaying black, but the text color is still brown.

I get these problems all the time, and the only way I can fix them is to write long, detailed styles, like this...

```
.Black, .Caption .Black, .CoolR .Caption.Black, .EverythingElseThatCouldBeBlack .Black { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: The example you provided works just fine if you put ``.Black`` declaration under the rules you want to override. http://jsfiddle.net/habTJ/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
.Black { background: #000 !important; color: #fff !important; }
```

Comment: You definitely could use `!important`, but it's better to understand CSS specificity before blindly overriding styles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating things. This will become a maintenance issue as you add more styles. I would define separate classes and keep things simple. It's also important to understand CSS specificity.

```
.caption {
  color: #000;
}

.cool-caption {
  color: #900;
}

.caption-with-background {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few fixes, but as previously recommended you should mark all of the settings you want to override previous ones with `!important`. With that, your code would look like this:

```
.Black { 
    background: #000; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

Also, not sure if you asked this, but you can apply `CSS` to all components by using the `*`, like so:

```
* {
    //blahblahblah
}
```

Comment: Wow, this turned into an educational discussion! I wasn't sure which to mark as the correct answer. I chose !important (which I had never even heard of before), because I'm still a little confused by CSS specificity. !important seems to be the only thing working for me at the moment, but I'll try and reorganize my code at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you are defining the first case with a descendant selector which overrides the second class, which is merely a class. every answer given already will *work* but are entirely unnecessary. just add this to your style sheet:

```
  
.CoolR1 .Black, .Black{ background: #000; color: #fff;}

/** you could also chain your classes for specificity power **/  
.Black.Caption{color:#fff}
```

that should do it. you can read more about selectors here:
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors

Answer (score 0):

I think that generally a more specific rule overrides a more general one, thus the more specific '.CoolR .Caption' is overriding the more general `.Black`.  You'll probably be able to override this with `!important`, but a better style might be to reduce the complexity of your rules:

```
.Cool .caption { color: #900; }

.Cool .caption.black { color: background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

And put `.L` and `.R` in separate classes

`.Cool.L { . . . } /*` For things specific to `CoolL`, but not `CoolR */`

`.Cool.R { . . . } /* and vice-versa *`/